# How to show user's own issues?

Tags: github, filter

I want to have prepared (linked in readme) search queries in my Github repository, that will help users work with issues. For example:

"Pullrequests I created, that are not ready for review"

or

"Issues that have label 'design' assigned to me"

It's easy to do for everyone manually - `is:pr author:myusername`, but the problem is when I want to share it. I couldn't find anything like `author:me`.

Comment: As of now, this doesn't seem to be possible.